# For, if, else statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, if-statement

So I have a multilayered problem. I am trying to I am trying to just print out 'input was jack' if the raw_input was 'jack' and also subtract 'tries' by 1, and then run the function again and print out amount of 'tries' at the end of both the first 'if' statement and the 'else' statement, and if the raw_input wasn't 'jack' it adds 1 to 'tries' and if 'tries' reaches a total of 4 the function prints stop. I have run into a couple of different problems. Either the counter seems to reset every single time so it's always just '1' or I can't just keep running the function. It just doesn't seem like it's following the 'if or else' theory I thought it would be. So I have the following code:

```
tries = 0
def usrinfo():
    name = raw_input('input name ')
    a = ('jill','jack',name,'meg')

    for element in a:
        if element == 'jack':
            print('input was jack')
            tries =-1
            print(tries)
            usrinfo()
    else:
        if element != 'jack':
            tries =+ 1
            return tries
            print(tries)
            usrinfo()
            if tries == 4:
                print('stopped')
usrinfo()
```

If I type 'jack' I get:

```
Nothing...as in a blank output
```

I want:

```
input was jack
-1
```

Then I want the function to run again...and get

```
input was jack
-2
```

And so on.

If I type anything other than 'jack' I get:

```
Nothing...as in a blank output
```

I want to get:

```
1
```

Then for the function to run again....and get

```
2
```

Then if I type anything other than 'jack'. I want with each attempt to print the increasing level of tries from 1 - 4 such as below:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Then when it reaches 4 it prints 'stopped' or runs whatever command. I want to essentially keep the code running and control the value of 'tries' according to whether or not the input is 'jack' or something else. Because even when I create an even simpler code like this:

```
def userinput():
    tries = 0
    username = raw_input('input username ')

    if username == 'jack':
        tries -=1
        print(username + ' '+ str(tries) + ' success')
        userinput()

    else:
        if username != 'jack':
            tries +=1
        print('tries ' + str(tries))
        userinput()
userinput()
```

My results on this code with input of 'f' are:

```
input username f
tries 1
input username f
tries 1
input username f
```

Instead I want to get:

```
input username f
tries 1
input username f
tries 2
input username f
tries 3
```

And with input of 'jack' I want:

```
input username jack
jack -1 success
input username jack
jack -2 success
input username jack
jack -3 success
input username jack
jack -4 success
```

And so on. Any help is much appreciated. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It just seems like 'tries' is constantly resetting itself.

Hopefully this is clear...I've spent a lot of time trying to make code just to be able to demonstrate to someone with more knowledge where my misunderstanding might be...

Thanks guys and gals.

Comment: Your else statement needs to align with the if statement, not on the same indentation as the for loop

Comment: Also, in the second block of code... Yes, you're calling the function again, and reseting a new `tries = 0`. Please use a while loop. Never call the function within itself. (This is called recursion, and it's a bad way to repeat an action in simple cases such as this)

Comment: You wrote ```return tries``` in the else clause so it's just returning... If you fix this your for loop will always match 'jack' because ```a = ('jill','jack',name,'meg')```

Comment: There's a difference between `tries =- 1` (first snippet) and `tries -= 1` (second snippet). The former sets `tries` to `-1`. The latter decrements `tries`.

Comment: There's also an `else` clause for [`for-loop`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Comment: Wow, lots of good feedback from you guys. Thanks so much. This is all very valuable info.

Comment: Isn't there some way for it to like "stop when matched" and continue on with the code using the match?

Comment: @NickolasKent Are you looking for `break`?

Comment: @abarnert Yup! I figured it out. I am pretty new, so I'm trying to avoid the "well this works here, so let me just throw it everywhere" mode, but I guess that's just a typical piece of the code if you want to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @NickolasKent That's a great attitude. The ideal way around that is that, whenever you see something that works but you don't understand why, do the research to figure out what it means. Sometimes reading the docs and thinking it through isn't enough, so an SO question can be helpful there. But be extra careful with your phrasing—a lot of people give less leeway to novice "Why does this code do this behavior?" questions than to harder ones unless it's obvious that you read the docs, played around, etc. For understandable reasons, but it can still be offputting.

Comment: @abarnert Yea, I try to exhaust all possibilities before coming to SO, and in the beginning I didn't really understand the part where SO wants to have kind of a "very basic" version of your code, but it makes sense now, because when I have to recreate what I'm trying to do in simpler terms I sometimes find my own answer, and it's a good learning process. Thanks for all your help by the way. I've noticed you chiming in on most of my posts and I really appreciate your input. I've only been coding for 3 weeks and I'm already working on my first fully fledged qt app utilizing sockets, threading..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with, no loops required

```
#!python3

from os import sys

def usrinfo(tries):
    name = input('input name: ')

    if tries == 4:
        print('end of program because tries equals 4')
        sys.exit()

    elif name == 'jack':
        tries -= 1
        print('input was jack')
        print('tries ' + str(tries) + '\n')
        usrinfo(tries)

    elif name != 'jack':
        tries += 1
        print('tries ' + str(tries) + '\n')
        usrinfo(tries)

usrinfo(0) # 'tries' will be initialized to zero
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are taking user input it is stored in the name variable so you need to do if with 'name' not 'element'. Secondly call the function after you have checked the condition

```
if tries == 4:
            print('stopped')
            return
        usrinfo()
```

Here is the correct code:

```
tries = 0
def usrinfo():
    global tries
    name = raw_input('input name ')
    a = ('jill','jack','meg')
    #to check the input against the strings of list a go for
    #if name in a: 
    if name == 'jack':
        print('input was jack')
        tries =-1
        print(tries)
        usrinfo()
    else:
        tries+=1
        print(tries)
        if tries == 4:
            print('stopped')
            return
        usrinfo()
usrinfo()
```